# FTP Server RETR Command Only Downloads Small Files

Tags: java, ftp, network-programming

For some reason, my code for my FTP server only allows me to transfer small file sizes. Does anyone know what could possibly be wrong with my code?
[Part of Server Code Here](http://www.centralark.org/random/)

```
private void Retr(String filename) {

    OutputStream output = null;

    sendOut("150 Preparando-se para tranferir arquivo");

    try {

        output = this.dataSocket.getOutputStream();
        File file = new File(this.fileManager.getPath() + File.separator
                + filename);

        System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
        RandomAccessFile reader = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw");
        byte[] fileBytes = new byte[1024];
        System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
        while (reader.getFilePointer() < reader.length())
            output.write(fileBytes, 0, reader.read(fileBytes));

        output.flush();
        output.close();

        sendOut("226 transferencia de " + filename + " concluída");

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

~~~~~The Log File Before It Failed~~~~~~

```
Status: Starting download of C:/Users/Public/desktop.ini
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 C:\Users
Command:    CWD C:/Users/Public/
Response:   200 cwd OK
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 C:\Users
Error:  Download failed
```

~~~~LOG FILE ON SUCCESS~~~~~~~~~~

```
Status: Starting download of C:/Users/roy_fCreated/ntuser.ini
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 Successfully Set TypeType I
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering passive mode (144,118,111,113,196,10)
Command:    RETR ntuser.ini
Response:   150 File status okay; about to open data connection
Response:   226 Closing data connection. Requested file action successful           ntuser.ini success!
Status: Download successful
```

Comment: What is "small file sizes"? What happens with larger files?

Comment: Files that are like 200 bytes and under are fine. Otherwise, it fails

Comment: Files that are like 200 bytes and under are fine. Otherwise, it fails

Log:
Status: Connected
Status: Starting download of C:/Users/All/setup.ini
Command: PWD
Response: 257 C:\Users
Command: CWD C:/Users/All/
Response: 200 cwd OK
Command: PWD
Response: 257 C:\Users
Error: Download failed
Command: TYPE A
Response: 200 Successfully Set TypeType A
Status: Disconnected from server

When I catch the exception and continue, the ftp client FileZilla would show a progress bar of it downloading but making no progress.

Comment: 1) Can you append the log your your question, to make it readable? 2) Isn't the threshold the 1024 bytes (size of your buffer)?

Comment: Yes, I just placed the log into the question for increased readability. Even more, I guess should I make the threshold bigger?

Comment: In does not make sense, there even no `RETR` command in the log. How does it look like for a small file?

Comment: I posted the log when it succeds. There it does have RETR. I am just not sure why it is not requesting RETR on the larger files.

Comment: Show us a complete log showing how you 1) enter and list a folder with both small and large files 2) download a small file 3) try to download a large file 4) download the same small file again

Comment: I posted a link to my code on my server. I'll make the log next.